# How can I exclude the Scratches directory from a custom scope

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a scope that I use to limit search results with, but the search results respond with matches from the Scratches directory which is not part of the Project

Comment: Hi @claya, Assuming you have intellij 2019.1.3 or higher: Custom Scopes for search do only contain projects/packages (Not scratches). Can you describe your topic in more detail please. pictures and a minimal working sample (on GitHub) would be nice too

Comment: There is a related bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211479. Is that the case?

Comment: @CrazyCoder looks similar to that known issue. thanks